# Export file to directory in Perl script

Tags: bash, perl, shell

I want to save file to directory using variable `$mid` which is defined in another BASH script in.  I am trying to use this code, but it doesn't work:

**Perl script to export file to folder**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $mid=$1;
my $filename = '/home/var/www/vids/$mid/${mid}_wer.txt';
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $fh "My first report generated by perl\n";
close $fh;
print "done\n"
```

In my work I also use some other BASH code in which I also use $mid variable to export file to the same folder and it works fine:

**Bash script to export file using $mid**

```
mid=$1
infile="/var/www/tmp/textgrid_uploads/${mid}.txt"
outfile="/home/var/www/vids/$mid/${mid}_textgrid.mlf"
tmpfile="/home/var/www/vids/$mid/${mid}.tmp"
```

I want to create PERL script with the same functionality as BASH script above. The same way how to export file to the directory as it is written in BASH. Please give me some example, I have never used Perl to write script and I need to create it till tommorow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` means something different in Perl.  The arguments to your program are stored in [`@ARGV`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#SPECIAL-VARIABLES), and are typically extracted with [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html).

```
my $mid = shift;
```

Variables aren't interpolated in single-quotes, but are in [double-quotes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

```
my $filename = "/home/var/www/vids/$mid/${mid}_wer.txt";
```